# CSS| Are 3D Absolute Items always on top of every other item?

Tags: css, 3d

so i have an issue, i am developing a website and i'm playing around with 3 dimensional cards. so the problem i run in is basically, no matter which z-index i give the div that should be above it, the card is still always in front. Is this an normal behavior or am i missing something? Thank you really much :)

[image]

Heres the HTML:

```
        <div class="project">
            <div class="project-title">
                <h1>someproject</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="project-scene">
                <div class="project-card">
                    <div class="project-face project-front">

                    </div>
                    <div class="project-face project-back">
                        <p>blablabla</p>
                        <img src="../assets/solarflarepi-presentation.gif">
                        <p>
                        blablabla
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And here is the css:

```
.project{
        border: white solid 0.3em;
        border-radius: 1em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        margin-left: 1em;
        flex: 1;
        align-items: center;
    }
    .project-card{
        background-color: transparent;
        width: 25em;
        height: 26em;
        position: relative;
        transition: transform 0.5s;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;

    }
    .project-scene{
        perspective: 1000px;   
    }
    .project-scene:hover .project-card{
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .project-face{
        position: absolute;
        backface-visibility: hidden;
        z-index: 0; /* The Div which should be above it has 5 */
    }

    .project-back .project-card{
        background-color: black;
    }
    .project-front{
        background-color: white;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }
    .project-back{
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        transform: rotateY(180deg);
    }
    .project-title{
        background-color: white;
        color: black;   
    }
    .project-title h1{
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0em 0.5em 0em 0.5em;
        font-weight: normal;
        text-align: center;
    }
    .project-back img{
        width: 25em;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case z-index do not fix your problem, you must use transform: translateZ(5);
like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBiVZ.png)

Comment: So I found the issue yesterday. It basically was me not understanding exactly how z-index works. The core issue was that I applied the z-index to the wrong css item, it was an item with an relative position. But z-Index apparently only works on: absolute, sticky and fixed items. After I changed this it immediately worked. It was the css of the Image Viewer which I didn’t provided here. But thanks for your answer nonetheless.